# Azure Api management - Can we change the header name

Tags: azure-api-management

In Azure API Management, When the client calls the API, the subscription key should be passed with the name "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" in the header. Can we change this name to something else?

Comment: got the answer
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/35af319b-2f2c-4ccb-91ef-3f526aa07a2b/azure-api-management-can-we-change-the-header-name?forum=azureapimgmt#35af319b-2f2c-4ccb-91ef-3f526aa07a2b

Answer (score 2):

got the answer, we can change the header name. but as of now its only supported from API.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/35af319b-2f2c-4ccb-91ef-3f526aa07a2b/azure-api-management-can-we-change-the-header-name?forum=azureapimgmt#35af319b-2f2c-4ccb-91ef-3f526aa07a2b